# Using RDOMail.Recipients.AddMultiple to add recipients to open Outlook mailitem

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I'm working on an Outlook add-in which uses Redemption. Part of the add-in's functionality is to allow users to add multiple recipients to a mailitem at once. Redemption's rdoRecipients object includes an "addmultiple" method that would improve the add-in's performance in this area. My code looks like this (rdoSession already created):

```
Redemption.RDOMail rdoMail = null;
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)activeInspector.CurrentItem;
if (mailItem != null)
{
    mailItem.Save();

    rdoMail = mAddinModule.RdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem);

    List<object> toList = new List<object>();

    // some code populating toList

    Array toRcps = toList.ToArray();

    rdoMail.Recipients.AddMultiple(toRcps, (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo);
    rdoMail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
    rdoMail.Save();

}
```

The code runs correctly.  Using OutlookSpy I can see that the MAPI recipient table includes the correct addresses. Also, if I add a line `rdoMail.Display()`, I get a new mailitem displayed with the correct addresses showing. However, the addresses do not display in the original Outlook mailitem. I'm guessing that changes to the Extended MAPI properties are not automatically reflected in the existing mailitem. Is there a way I can update the mailitem to show these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to add a user property using `MailItem.UserProperties.Add` (and then delete it) - that seems to force OOM to refresh the recipient list. I had luck with that approach before displaying the item using OOM; don't know if it will work while the item is already being displayed.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response, Dimitry. I tried the approach you suggested. Unfortunately, it didn't force refresh.I'm working through other attempts and will post if I find anything that works. In the meantime, if you have any other ideas, please do let me know.

Comment: Any chance you can add the recipients before the messages is shown?

Comment: The controls that allow users to add the recipients are actually embedded in form regions within the mailitem inspector itself, so the message needs to be open before the recipients are added.

Comment: In our anticipated use cases, it could range from just one or two at a time to a hundred or more. The add-in is not intended for internet marketing-scale distributions, where the performance cost of adding each recipient individually is crippling, but being able to use addmultiple (or some other method for adding multiple recipients in a single call) would be a significant performance enhancement.